# I have some error with firebase save data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this error

```
firebase.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reference.child failed: First   argument was an invalid path = "CUG04,CJS98,CJS17,CKJ50". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
at validatePathString (firebase.js:1)
at t.child (firebase.js:1) 
at database.ref.once.then.snapshots (generate-token.js:57)
```

Can you help me with this ?? I have many data in an one array , I want to set it in firebase database like a many child

this is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: link json

    success: function (data) {
        $('#resultat').html("fichier ");
        if (data != '') {
            myJsonObj = data
        }
        var taillemyJsonObj = myJsonObj.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < filteredAndMappedSubjects.length; j++) {
            console.log("ok");
            for (var i = 0; i < taillemyJsonObj; i++) {
                if (filteredAndMappedSubjects[j] === myJsonObj[i].title.en) {
                    sequenceid[i] = myJsonObj[i].sequenceId;     
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(sequenceid);
        resetUserInterface(sequenceid);
    },
});
```

This is my receive fobction who normaly set every sequenceid into the database firebase

```
function updateSubscriptiononserver(currentToken, sequenceid) {
if (isSubscribed) {
    ref.on('value', function (snap) {
        sequenceid = snap.val();
        console.log("okkk")
    })
    return database.ref("/tokens").orderBychild("uid").equalTo(currentToken)
        .on('child_added', snapshort => snapshort.ref.remove())
        console.log("okkk")
}
database.ref('/tokens').once('value')
    .then(snapshots => {
        let deviceExists = false
        snapshots.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            if (childSnapshot.val() === currentToken) {
                deviceExists = true
                return console.log('Device already registered.');
            }
        })
        console.log("oooooooo", sequenceid);
        if (!deviceExists) {
            return database.ref(`/tokens`).child(sequenceid).set({
                token: currentToken,
            })
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you want your database to look like after your writes?